# Directed angles problem: For $A$, $B$, $C$ on $\bigcirc O$, show that $\angle OAC=90^\circ-\angle CBA$

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

Directed angles problem from Evan Chen's book:

> Points $A$, $B$, $C$ lie on a circle with center $O$. Show that $$\measuredangle OAC=90^\circ-\measuredangle CBA$$ (This is not completely trivial.) **Hints:** 8 530 109

([original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUX2Q.png))

Hello Stackexchange! I can't solve this problem because I didn't understand directed angles completely. Solution with deep explanation would be amazing!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Example circle & triangle]

So we start by determening the value of $\measuredangle COA$. Since O is a central angle and $\measuredangle CBA$ is an inscribed angle based on the same segment $\overline{CA}$.
Since the central angle is two times the according inscribed angle (look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) for more information) we get $\measuredangle COA = 2\cdot\measuredangle CBA = 2\beta$.
Furthermore, looking at triangle $\triangle COA$, we notice that $\overline{CO}=\overline{AO}=R$, hence, the angles opposite to the sides will also be equal $\Rightarrow \measuredangle ACO = \measuredangle CAO = x$. Now we have an easy equation to solve by adding up all the angles:
$$x+x+(2\beta) = 180° = 2x+2\beta$$
$$x+\beta =90°$$
$$x = 90-\beta$$
If you have any questions, just ask them in comments!

Comment: Thank you very much! It's so easy in reality but I tried so many complicated steps. I think I have a mindset problem or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Extend the line $OA$ so that it intersects the circle at two points. One of them is $A$; the other one we can call it $A'$.

Below is one possible diagram; it is also possible that $O$ is not inside the triangle $\Delta ABC$, but the relationship between angles I mentioned below still holds.

I don't know how theorems are named in Evan's book, but all things I call theorem below should exist in his book.

[image: diagram of the problem]

#### One method:

One theorem says the arc corresponding to the inscribed angle $\angle OAC$ and $\angle CBA$ are arc $A'C$ and arc $AC$ respectively, and they together form half a circle.

The angle with vertex is at $O$ [called the central angle] corresponding of one full circle is $360$ degrees (like if you start at the ray $OA$ and swing a full round) whereas the central angle corresponding to half a circle is half of $360$ degrees. For the same arc the inscribed angle is always half the central angle. So inscribed angles corresponding to half a circle is half of half of $360$ degrees, which is $90$ degrees.

Since $\angle OAC$ and $\angle CBA$ together correspond to arcs adding up to half a circle, they adds up to $90$ degrees.

---

#### Justification the adds-up process above:

A theorem says all inscribed angle of the same arc equal each other. So $\angle OAC = \angle A'BC$. Thus $$\angle OAC+ \angle CBA = \angle A'BC + \angle CBA = \angle A'BA$$ The angle $\angle A'BA$ is an inscribed angle corresponding to the diameter, so it is $90^{\circ}$.

---

#### Same theorems applied in another order:

One theorem says, for the arc $A'C$, the central angle $\angle A'OC$ is twice the inscribed angle $\angle OAC$. For the arc $AC$ the central angle $\angle COA$ is also twice the inscribed angle $\angle CBA$.

In other words, $$\angle A'OC = 2\angle OAC, \ \ \ \angle COA = 2 \angle CBA.$$

We have $\angle A'OC + \angle COA = \angle AOA' = 180^{\circ}$. Substituting in the two equations above and dividing both sides by 2, we get
$$\angle OAC + \angle CBA = 90^{\circ}.$$
Rearrange for the desired equality.