# Problem with Directed Angles which sum to ${\pi \over 2}$.

Tags: geometry

I was solving a section in my book(EGMO Lemma 1.30) where the author discusses the uses of directed angles, when I came across-

> Points $A, B, C$ lie on a circle with center $O$. Show that $\measuredangle$ $OAC$ = $90^\circ$ − $\measuredangle$ $CBA$.

Let me denote directed angle with $\measuredangle$.(everywhere)

[image: Note the angles in blue.]

Here is an attempt; the author talks about the directed angles in blue, and it is to be shown that they sum to half $\pi$ radians. Lines in red are my own construction.

By directed angles, we know that $\measuredangle$ $CBA$ = $\measuredangle$ $CXA$ = ${1\over 2}$ $\measuredangle$ $COA$ (the inscribed angle theorem).
And also that $\measuredangle$ $OAC$ = $\measuredangle$ $ACO$ (triangle $OAC$ is isosceles).

Now by a theorem of directed angles, $\measuredangle$ $OAC$ $+$ $\measuredangle$ $ACO$ $+$ $\measuredangle$ $COA=0$

But after this, as we're working modulo $\pi$ radians, it's unintelligible to multiply or divide by $2$, which I have to do, so my attempt failed.

Answers are thankfully welcome.

Comment: Use `\angle` for displaying $\angle$. Also, include $+$ sign in `$$`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Directed angles problem: For $A$, $B$, $C$ on $\bigcirc O$, show that $\angle OAC=90^\circ-\angle CBA$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3690121/directed-angles-problem-for-a-b-c-on-bigcirc-o-show-that-angle-oa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By directed angles, we know that $\measuredangle$ $CBA$ = $\measuredangle$ $CXA$ = ${1\over 2}$ $\measuredangle$ $COA$ (the inscribed angle theorem).
> And also that $\measuredangle$ $OAC$ = $\measuredangle$ $ACO$ (triangle $OAC$ is isosceles).

> Now by a theorem of directed angles, $\measuredangle$ $OAC$ $+$ $\measuredangle$ $ACO$ $+$ $\measuredangle$ $COA=0$

After this we can write $2\times \measuredangle$ $OAC$ $+$ $\measuredangle$ $COA=0$
and resubstitute $\measuredangle$ $COA$ as $2\times \measuredangle$ $CBA$

We get, $2\times \measuredangle$ $OAC$ $+$ $2\times \measuredangle$ $CBA=0^\circ (\text{mod}\ 180^\circ)$

which is equivalent to writing as $2\times \measuredangle$ $OAC$ $+$ $2\times \measuredangle$ $CBA=180^\circ (\text{mod}\ 180^\circ)$

Divide both sides by $2$, and proceed to get $\measuredangle$ $OAC$ + $\measuredangle$ $CBA$ = $90^\circ \ (\text{mod}\ 90^\circ)$

`using : If a ≡ b (mod c) and gcd(c, d) = g then a/d ≡ b/d (mod c/g)`

Hence proved.

Comment: Dear Anindya, that is what I did. But it does not make sense to divide both sides by $2$ when working mod $180^\circ$.

Comment: Does that imply $\measuredangle OAC+\measuredangle CBA= 180^\circ$ also?

Comment: @BookOfFlames I suppose it does as long as mod is concerned also, $90^\circ$ is in mod90

Comment: @BookOfFlames : If a ≡ b (mod c) and gcd(c, d) = g then a/d ≡ b/d (mod c/g), saved changes to accomodate in the answer

Comment: @BookOfFlames d is the thing you divide with, which is 2 and gcd(2,180)=2

Comment: Okay, I haven't studied number theory, so well, Thanks for your time.

Comment: @BookOfFlames welcome, but you should complete prerequisites before choosing a topic ...on the bright side, you'll learn number theory on priority now, its fun :)

Comment: I know that number theory requires algebra and combinatorics as well. But algebra is very painful, so I gave up and picked geometry, Is it okay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111931/discussion-between-anindya-prithvi-and-book-of-flames).

Answer (score -2):

$\angle CBA \ne \angle CXA$, but $\angle CBA +\angle CXA =\pi$.

Comment: It's for usual angles, I wanted an answer involving directed angles. If they are not involving directed angles, they split into many cases.