# Lemma 1.30 in Evan Chen's EGMO book

Tags: geometry

> Page-15, Lemma 1.30: Points $A,B,C$ lie on a circle with center $O$. Show that $\measuredangle OAC= 90 - \measuredangle CBA$

Here we $\measuredangle CBA$ means the directed angle. I've seen this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3795097/problem-with-directed-angles-which-sum-to-pi-over-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) and linked already but I think neither has solutions in the way which was intended by the hint for the question.

I think so I got the idea how to solve it, but I'd like my solution be checked because this is one of my first times working with directed angles. Here goes:

#### Proof:

Begin by constructing the reflection of $A$ about $O$, call it $A'$. Notice that $\triangle  ACA'$ is right angled at $C$, hence:

$$ 90 +\measuredangle A_o A C + \measuredangle CA_o A=0$$

And by the inscribed angle theorem, I note that $ \measuredangle CBA = \measuredangle CA_o A$ and also $\measuredangle A_o A C= \measuredangle OAC$, upon substituting, I get:

$$ \measuredangle OAC  + \measuredangle CBA = 90$$

Is my solution well written? How could I make it better?

Here is a drawing I used for 'thinking' about the set up(slight error , reflected should be $A'$ not $A_o$):

[image]

And for $B$ on other side:
[image]

Turns out that exact same argument as said for the other case applies here (if the first proof was valid).

---

Note: Acc. to Evan chen's book sum of directed angle is zero,
[image]
page-12

Comment: Your first equation with your three angles has two issues. It should equal 180 since you're talking about the angles in a triangle and also you switched your notation of the reflected point from $A'$ to $A_0$. Other than that, this seems fine to me.

Comment: Hmm I am using the directed angles @X Stanton

Comment: Okay, then it is fine as others have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach -

[image]

Say $\angle ABC = \theta \ $. By inscribed angle theorem,

$\angle AOC = 2 \angle ABC = 2 \theta$.

As $OA = OC$, $\triangle AOC$ is isosceles triangle. So,

$\angle OAC = \angle OCA = \dfrac{180^0-2\theta}{2} = 90^0 - \theta$

Comment: Hi Math Lover, in the book I"m using it is said as a property of directed angles that the total angle sum in a triangle is zero

Comment: @Buraian yes my mistake. You mentioned directed angles. As we use opposite signs for clockwise and anti-clockwise angles, it will  add to zero.

Comment: Ah, does my proof look logically correct? @Math Lover

Comment: @Buraian yes your proof is fine. You may also want to consider the case when $B$ is on the other side of $AC$.

Comment: Hi!! @Math Lover I did as you told and found it gave the same result. I'll upload a pic for that

Comment: @Buraian looks good. Yes it would give the same result but to complete the proof, considering both case may be nice and hence suggested.